# Canvas moving shadow after clearRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to HTML5 and start learning canvas.

Currently, I am using canvas to make some objects rotate. The rectangle I created do move, however, I suffer from a problem, after the object move, some shadows remain as you can see from the image I captured.

[image]

I just want to have the rectangle, and not including the blue background clumsy stuff. I try to use different browsers to view this HTML5 document, but same problem comes out. Is this a problem of my computer, or is it a problem of the code? If so, how can I solve it?

I have also attached my source code of rotating rectangle example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/ogoj9odf/1/

Here is my key code:

In Javascript:

```
function canvaScript() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    context.translate(200, 200); // fix the origin as center of the canvas
    rotating(context); 
}

function rotating(context) {
    context.clearRect(-50, -100, 100, 200); // why boundaries, shadows exist??
    context.rotate(Math.PI/180); 
    context.fillStyle = '#0000FF'; 
    context.fillRect(-50, -100, 100, 200); 

    setTimeout(function() {rotating(context)}, 100); 
}
```

In HTML

```
<body onload="canvaScript()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>  
</body>
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm not sure about this glitch, but what I personally did in that situation, was to use a slightly larger clearRect than the shape I had to clear. (Ps: it seems to be the same source of glitch that the one you get when you draw multiple times in the same place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem probably comes from the anti-aliasing.

You can see it by clearing directly after you drawn your rotated shape :

```js
function canvaScript() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    context.translate(200, 200); // fix the origin as center of the canvas
    context.rotate(Math.PI/4);
    rotating(context); 
}

function rotating(context) {
    context.fillStyle = '#0000FF'; 
    context.fillRect(-50, -100, 100, 200); 
 context.clearRect(-50, -100, 100, 200); 
}

canvaScript();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

So one solution to workaround this is to clear a slightly larger `clearRect` than the rect you just drawn.

```js
function canvaScript() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

    context.translate(200, 200); // fix the origin as center of the canvas
    rotating(context); 
}

function rotating(context) {
    // clear one extra pixel in all directions
    context.clearRect(-51, -101, 102, 202); 
    context.rotate(Math.PI/180); 
    context.fillStyle = '#0000FF'; 
    context.fillRect(-50, -100, 100, 200); 

    setTimeout(function() {rotating(context)}, 100); 
}

canvaScript();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks... the above code really work... maybe I am stupid... why do I need to provide a bit larger clearRect()? Of course, I understand why it works. BUT why don't my idea work? If the rect I draw is really in this size, then if I clearRect using the same size, I should clear everything, isn't it? OR do I have anything misconceptions? Thanks.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I think that this *bug*, as I consider it is one, comes from the anti-aliasing, doing some random things... You can try for instance to run a hundred times in a row my first snippet and you'll see that the rectangle thickness will increase. http://jsfiddle.net/m7b0unp0/1/